# Using Apple Pay and Stripe in Apple Testflight

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, testflight, applepay

I'm creating an iOS app where I'm using Stripe and Apple Pay and I would like to have the full functionality of Stripe and Apple Pay when I test on external users using Apple's Testflight.

I'm not sure if there are any restrictions in relation to having live transfer in a Testflight app though? Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Are you referring to technical or policy restrictions?

Comment: @BradBrighton Both... does Apple apply any technical restrictions in Testflight and do they have any policy restrictions? I don't think Stripe would impose anything like that, so it's Apple I'm worried about here.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I also uploaded a build with live publishable key and live secret key in Firebase Cloud Functions and cannot sign up on my app anymore.